# Foreign key Bit values of SQL Server underlying members UpdateAction and DeleteAction

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys, vssdk

Does anyone know where I can find documentation on the bit values for SqlServer's ForeignKey underlying members UpdateAction and DeleteAction.

They are type Int32 but I am struggling to find any documentation on how the bits in each equate to No Action, Cascade, Set Null etc.

I have to provide the mapped integer values of each converted from Firebird's values to use in the Visual Studio IDSRefBuilder AppendToDSRef drag and drop service.

Comment: Which system object(s) are you talking about here? Many of the system views have documentation, such as [sys.foreign_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-key-columns-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah thanks @Larnu.
Exactly what I was looking for.It's delete_referential_action and update_referential_action under [sys.foreign_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).